# How do I draw the integration path in the complex plane in the case with two branch cuts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, plot, integral, contour

This is the picture of a graph I would like to plot. This is what I have tried to do, what is missing is how to align all of the points properly so that it looks nice.

[image: sketch]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw [->] (-5.5,0) -- (5.5,0) node [below right]  {$\mathfrak{Re}(z)$};
  \draw [->] (0,-5.5) -- (0,5.5) node [above ] {$\mathfrak{Im}(z)$};
  %Branch cuts
  \draw [decorate,decoration={zigzag,segment length=2,amplitude=1,post=lineto,post length=10}] (cos 45,sin 45) -- (5*cos 45,5*sin 45);
  \draw [decorate,decoration={zigzag,segment length=2,amplitude=1,post=lineto,post length=10}] (cos -45,sin -45) -- (5*cos 45,5*sin -45);
  %Path gamma1
  \draw [->] (0.7*cos 45, 0.3+0.7*sin 45 ) -- (5*cos 45,0.3+5*sin 45);
  %Path gamma2
  \draw [->] (1.12426*cos 45, -0.3+1.12426*sin 45 ) -- (5.424264*cos 45,-0.3+5.424264*sin 45);
  %Connecting gamma 1 and gamma 2
  \draw [-]  (0.7*cos 45, 0.3+0.7*sin 45 ) -- (1.12426*cos 45, -0.3+1.12426*sin 45 );
  %Path gamma 3
  \draw [->] (1.12426*cos 45, 0.3+1.12426*sin -45 ) -- (1.12426*5*cos 45,0.3+5*1.12426*sin -45);
  %Path gamma 4
  \draw [->] (0.7*cos 45, -0.3+0.7*sin -45 ) -- (5*1.12426*cos 45,-0.3+1.12426*5*sin -45);
  %Connecting gamma 3 and gamma 4
  \draw [-]  (1.12426*cos 45, 0.3+1.12426*sin -45 ) -- (0.7*cos 45, -0.3+0.7*sin -45 );
  %Gamma R
  % \draw plot [smooth] coordinates {(5.424264*cos 45,-0.3+5.424264*sin 45) (5*cos 25, 5* sin 25) (5,0 )  (1.12426*5*cos 45,0.3+5*1.12426*sin -45)};
  \draw [-] (5.424264*cos 45,-0.3+5.424264*sin 45) arc (45:-45:5*1.001cm);
  \draw [-] (5*cos 45,0.3+5*sin 45) arc (45:310.3:5*1.001cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. What did you try?

Comment: Start here: https://tikz.dev/tutorials-guidelines .

Comment: Welcome. Unfortunately, this is not a "please do this for me" site. Your question should focus on a specific problem you are having with this diagram. To get some ideas how you might approach this, you might look at [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/575200/125871) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/78154/125871) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/298795/125871) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103176/125871) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/560582/125871).